# Overlap of a date with an array of date intervals

Tags: ruby, intervals

Given an array of date ranges:

```
[date_range1, date_range2, date_range3, date_range4, ...]
```

and a date range like

```
given_date_range = (date_whithin_date_range1 .. date_between_date_range2_and_date_range3)
```

how can I return an array of uncovered intervals between range elements in the array which are within `given_date_range`?
For this case, it should return

```
[[date_range1.end + 1, date_range2.begin - 1],  
[date_range2.end + 1, date_between_date_range2_and_date_range3.end]]
```

An example with actual values:

```
given_date_range = (Date.new(2014, 7, 3) .. Date.new(2016, 3, 18))


array_of_date_ranges = [(Date.new(2014, 5, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 10)), 
                        (Date.new(2015, 3, 2) .. Date.new(2015, 4, 9)), 
                        (Date.new(2016, 3, 5) .. Date.new(2016, 4, 8)),
                        (Date.new(2016, 6, 2) .. Date.new(2016, 7, 3)),
                                             ...                    ]
```

Expected result:

```
[[Date.new(2014, 8, 11), Date.new(2015, 3, 1)],  
 [Date.new(2015, 4, 10), Date.new(2016, 3, 4)]]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by a date range. Is it a range object? Or an Array?

Comment: Why is `date_between_date_range2_and_date_range3.end` in the result when it wasn't in the original array?

Comment: What happens if range2 includes range3? Can you give examples with the actual values?

Comment: @ndn It won't happen, because intervals in the array don't overlap.

Comment: @Sajjad, you forgot to add `given_date_range` for your example. Also `(Date.new(2014, 5, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 10)).end != Date.new(2014, 8, 11)`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Array operations

Since the ranges don't have too many elements, it's acceptable to convert them to arrays of Dates.

We remove all the `date_ranges` Dates from `given_date_range` to get an Array of uncovered dates. We slice this Array on non-consecutive days, and convert the resulting Array of Arrays of Dates to an Array of Date Ranges :

```
require 'date'

date_ranges = [(Date.new(2014, 5, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 10)),
              (Date.new(2015, 3, 2) .. Date.new(2015, 4, 9)),
              (Date.new(2016, 3, 5) .. Date.new(2016, 4, 8)),
              (Date.new(2016, 6, 2) .. Date.new(2016, 7, 3))]

given_date_range = (Date.new(2014, 7, 3) .. Date.new(2016, 3, 18))

uncovered_dates = given_date_range.to_a - date_ranges.flat_map(&:to_a)
puts uncovered_dates.sort
                    .slice_when { |d1, d2| d1 + 1 != d2 }
                    .map { |free_range| (free_range.first..free_range.last) }
#=>
# 2014-08-11..2015-03-01
# 2015-04-10..2016-03-04
```

## Gem for Range operations

You can use this [gem](https://github.com/monocle/range_operators) to add arithmetic operations on Ranges.

It begins with the complete range, and substracts every range one after the other.

Since substracting a range from another can result in two ranges, the script actually begins with `[complete_range]` and keeps an array of ranges between iterations :

```
require 'date'
require 'range_operators'

date_ranges = [(Date.new(2014, 5, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 8, 10)),
              (Date.new(2015, 3, 2) .. Date.new(2015, 4, 9)),
              (Date.new(2016, 3, 5) .. Date.new(2016, 4, 8)),
              (Date.new(2016, 6, 2) .. Date.new(2016, 7, 3))]

#given_date_range = date_ranges.first.min .. date_ranges.last.max # assuming the ranges are sorted
given_date_range = (Date.new(2014, 7, 3) .. Date.new(2016, 3, 18))

uncovered = date_ranges.inject([given_date_range]) do |free_ranges, range|
  free_ranges.flat_map do |free_range|
    free_range - range
  end
end

puts uncovered
# => 2014-08-11..2015-03-01
#    2015-04-10..2016-03-04
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require "date"

(array_of_date_ranges.flat_map(&:to_a) & given_date_range.to_a)
.uniq.sort.chunk_while{|x, y| x.next == y}
.flat_map{|x, *, y| [x, y]}[1...-1]
.each_slice(2)
.map{|x, y| [x + 1, y - 1]}
# => [
  [#<Date: 2014-08-11 ((2456881j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2015-03-01 ((2457083j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>],
  [#<Date: 2015-04-10 ((2457123j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2016-03-04 ((2457452j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder that it's acceptable to use Array arithmetics. Last example I had with Ranges had millions of elements, so it would have been slow. For your solution, using `Array#-` instead of `Array#&` would simplify the code a lot. AFAIK, `Array#&` is a Set operation, so `uniq` is probably redudant.

Comment: This method doesn't work for `given_date_range = (Date.new(2014, 4, 10) .. Date.new(2014, 6, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: update answer to reflect changes in question.

I have solved this in most readable way until now I think.
I didn't use Dates, but integers - it will work the same.

```
# helper function
def discover_extras(two_ranges, given_range)
  first = two_ranges.first
  last = two_ranges.last

  if given_range.cover?(first.end)
    if given_range.cover?(last.begin)
      first.end+1..last.begin-1
    else
      first.end+1..given_range.end if given_range.end > first.end
    end
  else
    nil
  end
end

def values_not_covered_in(ranges, given_range)
  not_covered = []

  ranges.each_cons(2) do |two_ranges|
    extras = discover_extras(two_ranges, given_range)
    not_covered.push(extras) if extras
  end

  not_covered
end
```

Here is the spec file I used to verify it all

```
require "dates_not_covered"

describe '#discover_extras(two_ranges, given_range)' do
  it 'when before range returns nil' do
    expect(discover_extras([2..10, 12..15], 0..1)).to be nil
  end

  it 'when covers first range returns nil' do
    expect(discover_extras([2..10, 12..15], 2..10)).to be nil
  end


  it 'when includes both ranges returns between ranges' do
    expect(discover_extras([2..10, 13..15], 2..15)).to eq(11..12)
  end

  it 'for [2..10, 12..15] and 2..11 returns 11..11' do
    expect(discover_extras([2..10, 12..15], 2..11)).to eq(11..11)
  end
end

describe '#values_not_covered_in(ranges, given_range)' do
  it 'for [2..10, 12..15] and 2..10 returns []' do
    expect(values_not_covered_in([2..10, 12..15], 2..10)).to eq []
  end

  it 'for [2..10, 12..15] and 2..11 returns [11..11]' do
    expect(values_not_covered_in([2..10, 12..15], 2..11)).to eq([11..11])
  end

  it 'for [2..10, 12..15] and 2..15 returns [11..11]' do
    expect(values_not_covered_in([2..10, 12..15], 2..15)).to eq([11..11])
  end

end
```

Once again, this works for both ints and dates.
Only difference is that I have decided to return an array of ranges, not array with range start and end. I think it's better this way.

If you insist on returning array of arrays, then just convert those ranges to array

```
not_covered.push([extras.begin, extras.eng]) if extras
```

Comment: Writing tests is good, writing tests corresponding to what the OP needs is better. The ranges your method outputs aren't correct.

Comment: It wasn't really clear what he wants when I started working on this. In what way are outputs not correct?

Comment: I see he changed this to add or substract 1. `[date_range1.end + 1, date_range2.begin - 1]`   My solution is for what he wanted first time.

Comment: Okay. Regardless of this : `values_not_covered_in([2..10, 12..15], 2..15)` 10 and 12 are covered, they really shouldn't be in the output Range.

Comment: It should have been according to original requirements. Now it should just be 11..11

Comment: Okay, I see the edit. Since Ruby is a dynamic language, I tend to accord a lot of importance to method names.

Comment: I have changed it. Not going to change it anymore, spent way too much time on this.